# Porque no se muestra el icono de notificacion con la pantalla bloqueada?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Mientras tenga el celular desbloqueado y este en mi aplicacion las notificaciones llegan muy bien como deberia ser pero cuando bloqueo o salgo de la aplicacion llegan con un icono predeterminad de android. 
Llevo bastantes dias y no he encontrado informacion clara y precisa sobre esto, confio en que ya le ha pasado a alguien mas.
Ya he probado todas las dimensiones como lo dice la documentacion y aun sigue igual.

> ***La primera notificacion es cuando el dispositivo esta activo y la segunda es cuando se encuentra bloqueado. Mi version api 23***

```
                builder.setContentTitle(title)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_corazon))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notificacion_cereza)
                        .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentLight))
                        .setContentText(aMessage) 
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(aMessage))
                        .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_lounch_add, context.getResources().getString(R.string.seguir_comprando), pendingIntent))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que hay un mal entendido, la segunda notificación jalala hacia abajo con dos dedos y dime si aparece el corazón. @yefrigarcia ¿Como se llama la imagen de la segunda notificación?

Comment: @Jorgesys, no sucede nada. Ambas notificaciones pertenecen al mismo builder, en lo unico que deberian variar es en sus mensajes como lo esta haciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal el problema que tienes y creo que es porque en tu manifest no esta implementado este codigo en tu manifest :

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```